Android studio doesnt find android sdk in wsl path
I'm trying to use Android Studio installed on windows with all the resources installed on wsl  (gradle, jdk, sdk, project files...)
I've installed and configured everything as needed, but when im trying to build the project im getting an error
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\...\projects\...
No traceback or anything but I'm also getting this warning under "Sync"
SDK location not found. Define a location by setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local.properties file
The weird thing is that everything is indeed configured as it suggests.
My local.properties file:
sdk.dir=\\\\wsl.localhost\\Ubuntu\\usr\\lib\\android-sdk
Things i did:

Configured that android sdk path also through Android Studio settings
Deleted local.properties file / .gradle folder / .idea folder
Configured ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME paths both in windows and in wsl
Changed both gradle versions and jdk versions to see if any version might be the problem
Changed gradle home path to be in wsl (/home/user/.gradle)
Configured gradle jdk path to be the one installed in the WSL environment (//wsl.localhost/Ubuntu/home/user/.jdks/jbr-17.0.12)

Nothing works.
Something i noticed:

In the gradle settings page in the jdk path selection, there are the JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME options, they aren't pointing to the actual environment variable configured neither on windows and neither on WSL, so my first guess would be there is an issue with Android Studio trying to read the environment variables


When i'm running ./gradlew assembleDebug through the terminal, it succeeds
But now i see the warning sdk.dir property in local.properties file. Problem: Directory does not exist



I've been trying to solve it for almost a week now any help will be appreciated!

I don't think it is a good idea to access WSL software from outside of WSL environment. The SDK also contains executable files - which means Linux LF executables that can not be executed on Windows outside of WSL environment.
